# Как получит обновление, кто пригласил, в группу контакты?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Подскажите, как получить информацию, чтобы текст, примерно такой был, например: Наталья пригласила 20 контактов в группу.

Почитал документацию, чтобы получить обновление, нужен ChatMemberUpdated new_chat_member для message нужен new_chat_members, но когда добавляю контакты в группу, ничего не пишет, в группе, от имени бота, ошибок нет.

Слепил, подскажите, как прописать код, чтобы работал, как надо.

```html
@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.NEW_CHAT_MEMBERS)
#async def check_new_user(message: types.Message):
async def new_member(message, update: types.ChatMemberUpdated):
    invited_user = message.new_chat_members[0].full_name
    user_invited = message.from_user.full_name
    
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    new_chat_members = message.new_chat_members
    new_chat_member = update.new_chat_member
    ChatMemberUpdated.from_user.full_name = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=message.chat.id, user_id=message.from_user.id)

    for update.new_chat_member in message.new_chat_members:
        if ChatMemberUpdated.new_chat_member in message.new_chat_members:
                    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"{user_invited=} - {invited_user=}".format(message.from_user.id, message.new_chat_member), parse_mode='html', disable_notification=True, disable_web_page_preview=True)
                    return
```

Comment: узнать кто добавлял в группу сколько человек нельзя, можно отслеживать и сохранять в бд когда он добавляет. и ещё можно создать ссылки-приглашения, и тут можно узнать сколько человек добавились в группу по этой ссылке

Comment: А как, все это прописать, в бд, когда добавляет и вывести текст, в группу?

Comment: в ютубе есть очень много туторов по бд и вообще по считыванию добавленных пользователей

Comment: название ролика напишите, или название канала.